# Applying group aggregation over multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I'm playing around with Pandas. 
Given

`day  pokemon     date                          cp
14   Abra        2016-11-14 14:08:37.205617    377
                 2016-11-14 22:47:02.467526    374
     Bellsprout  2016-11-14 09:02:41.420506    460
                 2016-11-14 09:31:29.026961    541
                 2016-11-14 09:42:49.151360    125`

I'd like to add a new colum for each *pokemon* value where the group relate *cp* mean is inserted.
As you probably think, this is a multiIndex structure where (day, pokemon, date) is the index tuple.

Until now I tried to solve this problem merging this dataframe with the one obtained by grouping by *day* and *pokemon* and applying the mean operation. A a result, I loose the *date* field and I'm still not able to merge it the one I posted above.

My expected result would be something like this:

```
day  pokemon     date                          cp   mean
14   Abra        2016-11-14 14:08:37.205617    377  
                 2016-11-14 22:47:02.467526    374  375.5
     Bellsprout  2016-11-14 09:02:41.420506    460
                 2016-11-14 09:31:29.026961    541
                 2016-11-14 09:42:49.151360    125  375.3
```

How would you solve this?
Thanks, FB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) first and then add `NaN` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` by inverting [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
g = df.groupby(level=[0,1])
df['mean'] = g['cp'].transform('mean')
df['mean'] = df['mean'][g['mean'].apply(lambda x: ~x.duplicated(keep='last'))]
print (df)
                                            cp        mean
day pokemon    date                                       
14  Abra       2016-11-14 14:08:37.205617  377         NaN
               2016-11-14 22:47:02.467526  374  375.500000
    Bellsprout 2016-11-14 09:02:41.420506  460         NaN
               2016-11-14 09:31:29.026961  541         NaN
               2016-11-14 09:42:49.151360  125  375.333333
```

Comment: So easy! Can I get just one value for each group?

Comment: Yes, second part is hard.